# AudioKit - help showing 5 seconds of complete waveform in EZAudioPlot

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am generating a EZAudioPlot for my iOS app from a complete recording as shown below:

```
let audioFile = EZAudioFile(url: 
getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(currentRecording.fileName))

guard let data = audioFile?.getWaveformData() else {return nil}

let plot = EZAudioPlot()
plot.plotType = .buffer
plot.shouldFill = true
plot.shouldMirror = true
plot.color = UIColor.red
plot.updateBuffer(data.buffers[0], withBufferSize: data.bufferSize)
waveformView.addSubview(plot)
```

This is great and generates the waveform for the whole recording. However, I want to only show 5 seconds or so (which seems to be a buffersize of 200) of this complete waveform on the screen and have it scroll along as the recording plays back.

Do I need to create multiple plots, each with a buffersize of 200?  Or perhaps generate an CIImage from this waveform that I can use in a scroll view? I also saw the circular buffer utilities and thought maybe I should use those.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for making such an amazing framework!!